# Debugger statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, debugging

In JavaScript there is the [*debugger;*](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp) statement that stops execution and acts as a break point. In C# there is the *[Debugger.Break()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.8)* method with almost identical behavior. Does in PowerShell exist something similar?

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help *breakpoint*` & `Get-Help *debug*` for a few ideas. [*grin*]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Wait-Debugger` is the PowerShell equivalent.

Comment: That does the job! Works like my function ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with this simple PowerShell function that does the job

```
Function Set-PSBreakPointHere {

  $line = [int] $Myinvocation.ScriptlineNumber + 1 # following line
  $script = $Myinvocation.PSCommandPath

  # set a break point that pauses execution 
  Set-PSBreakpoint -Line $line -Script $script |  Out-Null

  # set a break point that removes the previous break and itself 
  Set-PSBreakpoint -Line $line -Script $script -Action { $breakPOint = Get-PSBreakpoint -Script $script | Where Line -EQ $line | Remove-PSBreakpoint }.GetNewClosure() | Out-Null

}
```

This function creates two break points on the line at the script where it is invoked. One of the breakpoints stops the execution and enters the debugger (that is what I wanted) and the other breakpoint unregisters both of these break points to keep things clean.